# Multiple special character transformations on dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I wish to keep everything before the hyphen in one column, and keep everything before the colon in another column using Pandas.

### Data

```
ID            Type               Stat

AA - type2    AAB:AB33:77:000    Y
CC - type3    CCC:AB33:77:000    N
```

### Desired

```
ID    Type

AA    AAB
CC    CCC
```

### Doing

```
separator = '-'
result_1 = my_str.split(separator, 1)[0]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `df[['ID', 'Type']] = df[['ID', 'Type']].apply(lambda col: col.str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False), axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `str.extract` here:

```py
df["ID"] = df["ID"].str.extract(r'(\w+)')
df["Type"] = df["Type"].str.extract(r'(\w+)')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say

```py
func1 = lambda _: _['ID'].split('- ')[0]
func2 = lambda _: _['Type'].split(':')[0]

data\
  .assign(ID=func1)\
  .assign(Type=func2)
```

**References**
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html